# how to avoid switch statement?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to learn client/server in java
until now i got the basics.
here how to accept and serve out many clients

```
public class Server {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void startServer() throws IOException {
        serverSocket= new ServerSocket(2000);
        while (true){
            Socket s= serverSocket.accept();
            new ClientRequestUploadFile(s).start(); //here is the first option.
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose i have too many type of options the client can request.
the code will be as follow :

```
public void startServer() throws IOException {
        serverSocket= new ServerSocket(2000);
        while (true){
            Socket s= serverSocket.accept();
            DataInputStream clientStream= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String requestName=clientStream.readUTF();
            switch (requestName){
                case "ClientRequestUploadFile": new ClientRequestUploadFileHandler(s).start();break;
                case "clientRequestCalculator": new clientRequestCalculatorHandler(s).start();break;
                case "clientRequestDownloadFile": new clientRequestDownloadFileHandler(s).start();break;
            }
        }
    }
```

if there 100 of options,**is there any way to avoid switch statement(design-patterns maybe)?**
keep in mind that may occur new option in the future.

Comment: Use a command pattern. Look up the appropriate command from a map using the string as a key, and execute() it.

Comment: I think what you can't avoid, is testing each case, independently from a switch-case or for-loop. You could try making things in a clever way (for example check if your string is starting by "ClientRequest" to avoid testing all of your 3 cases if the string is something else).

Comment: @azurefrog can u give me an example plz? :)

Comment: Create an `enum` with both the request name and the command creation, and iterate all values until you found a match.

Comment: @daniu what you mean by command creation?

Comment: somehow that makes me think of [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) - services (or *request handlers*) can be added without having to recompile

Comment: @user85421 I didn't know about that, but it's not surprising.  Today's design pattern is tomorrow's language feature. My original pattern book talks about how to implement the Iterator pattern... ;-)

Comment: @user85421 hi dude i'm very thankful for your comment, could u give me a good resources for bot of them, or before that, in same project i'm currently working on the server should sent to client function to execute,(basically a map function-MapReduce framework), but the code on client side is compiled, so i need to add method added without having to recompile.

Comment: I just have the posted link (see my first comment/standard Java SE javadoc) - it was enough when I did implement such a *service*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an example where something like the Command pattern would be appropriate.

Basically, you want a way to map a given command (in this case, a `String`), into executing the appropriate behavior.

The simplest way to do this would be to create a Command interface like so:

```
interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

Then you can create a `Map<String, Command>` that holds your commands and maps each incoming `String` into some helper class that implements `Command` and does the thing you want to happen when you see that command. Then you would use it something like:

```
commandMap.get(requestName).execute();
```

This will, however, require a bit of on-the-fly setup at program startup to build the Map with the command strings and the Command objects.  This is a very dynamic way of setting up the mapping, which may be a good or bad thing depending on how often your command set changes.

If your commands are more static, a more elegant way to set this up would be to use an `enum` to define the various commands and their behaviours.  Here's a fairly simple and generic example of how you could do that:

```
public class CommandPatternExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CommandEnum.valueOf("A").execute(); // run command "A"
        CommandEnum.valueOf("B").execute(); // run command "B"
        CommandEnum.valueOf("C").execute(); // IllegalArgumentException
    }

    interface Command {
        void execute();
    }

    enum CommandEnum implements Command {
        A {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Running command A");
            }
        },
        B {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Running command B");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, there's no way to get around having the command to helper object mapping *somewhere* in your code.  The main thing is to not have it in your business logic, which makes the method hard to read, but rather in its own class somewhere.

Comment: Well this vary clear and thank u for that, more one question please , in my case is it okay to  do something like this ?        A {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                new ClientRequestUploadFileHandler(s).start();
            }

Comment: Sure, but you'd need to modify the Command interface so that its execute method accepts the socket as a parameter so that it's visible in the helper method.  Also, keep in mind that the names of the enums need to match the command strings, so it'd be something like `ClientRequestUploadFile { @Override public void execute(Socket s) { new ClientRequestUploadFileHandler(s).start(); } }`

Answer (score 0):

So what you have is a large-ish `switch` block that in the end `start()`s some piece of code. The recommended way is to use existing interfaces, so that would be a `Runnable` (containing a `void` method with no parameters, just like your `start()`).

If you refactor the whole block out into a method, it would have two inputs: the `Socket` and the the `requestName` - so its signature would look like this:

```
Runnable getRequestCommand(Socket s, String request)
```

which would contain your `switch` block and returned something like

```
if ("ClientRequestUploadFile".equals(request)) {
    return new ClientRequestUploadFileHandler(s);
} 
// etc
```

Again using preexisting interfaces, this is a `BiFunction<Socket, String, Runnable>` (it requires the request string and the socket as input and returns the handler runnable).

Now you can split each individual `case` and create such a function:

```
BiFunction<Socket, String, Runnable> upload = (s, req) -> {
    return "ClientRequestUploadFile".equals(req) 
        ? new ClientRequestUploadFileHandler(s)
        : null;
}
```

If you do the same for the other cases and store these in a `Collection<BiFunction<Socket, String, Runnable>>` (let's call it `handlers`), your `getRequestCommand()` method above looks like

```
Runnable requestHandler = null;
for (BiFunction<Socket, String, Runnable> handler : handlers) {
    requestHandler = handler.apply(s, request);
    if (requestHandler != null) { break; } // found the match
}
return requestHandler;
```

Now your `switch` actually also starts the created `Runnable`, so you can also `if (requestHandler != null) { requestHandler.run(); }` here and not return it back to the caller. As a single line, this is `handlers.stream().map(h -> h.apply(s, request)).findFirst(Objects::nonNull).ifPresent(Runnable::run)`.

Anyway, now you're stuck with creating all the `BiFunction<>`s in the original class, but you can externalize them, eg. to an `enum`.

```
enum RequestHandler {
    FILE_UPLOAD("ClientRequestUploadFile", ClientRequestUploadFileHandler::new),
    CALCULATE("clientRequestCalculator", ClientRequestCalculatorHandler::new),
    // ...
    ;

    // the String that needs to match to execute this handler
    private String request;
    // creates the runnable if the request string matches
    private Function<Socket, Runnable> createRunnable;

    private RequestHandler(String r, Function<Socket, Runnable> f) {
        request = r; createRunnable = f;
    }
    // and this is your handler method
    static void runOnRequestMatch(Socket socket, String request) {
        for (RequestHandler handler : values()) {
            Runnable requestHandler = request.equals(handler.request) 
                                          ? handler.createRunnable.apply(socket)
                                          : null;
            if (requestHandler != null) {
                requestHandler.run();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your client code, you'd get

```
// ...
Socket s= serverSocket.accept();
DataInputStream clientStream= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
String requestName=clientStream.readUTF();
RequestHandler.runOnRequestMatch(s, requestName);
```

Now you've ended up with far more code than before, but the handling itself is removed from the class accepting the socket, so better single responsibility; this allows you to add functionality by adding a value to the `enum` without needing to touch your original code.

A simpler version would be to create the functions collection in a method by simply doing

```
Collection<BiFunction<Socket,String,Runnable>> createMappings() {
    return Arrays.asList(
        createMapping("ClientRequestUploadFile", ClientRequestUploadFileHandler::new),
        createMapping("clientRequestCalculator", ClientRequestCalculatorHandler::new),
    );
}
private BiFunction<Socket,String,Runnable> createmapping(String req, Function<Socket, Runnable> create) {
    return (s, r) -> req.equals(r) ? create.apply(s) : null;
}
```

Comment: You are an artist

Comment: dude i'm now work on project, i'm fresh graduate, can i take your opinion in some project, not large project almost 50 classes. (this project can help to get a job), i will do all thing u just give me note plz :)